# trying to find a relationship between $ker f$ and $Im f$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve the following exercise but can't get anywhere:

**The problem:**

*$E$ an euclidian space*

$f \in \mathscr{L}(E), (. | .) $ a scalar product on $E$

$\forall x \in E, (f(x) \:|\: x) \: = 0$

Compare $\operatorname {ker} f$ and $\operatorname {Im} f$

**What I've tried :**

I'm trying to find a relationship between the two sets. To do that, I've declared two variables, $x, y \in \operatorname {ker}(f) * \operatorname {Im}(f)$ and expanded $( f(x+y)\:|\: x+y) \:= 0$ using multi-linearity of the scalar product. I end up getting $(f(x)\:|\:y) + (f(y)\:|\:x) \:= \:(f(x+y)\:|\:x+y) \:= 0$ but I have no idea how to progress further.

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: By the notation $\mathscr{L}(E)$ do you mean linear operators on $E$? Do you care if $E$ is over the complex or real?

Comment: Have you learned about the "adjoint" to a transformation?

Comment: @BenGrossmann No I didn't

Comment: @AndréArmatowski Yes it's linear operators, $\mathscr{L}(E)$ means linear function which takes input E, output E. I do not care if it's complex or real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your work, we deduce that for any $x,y \in E$, we have
$$
(f(x) \mid y) + (f(y) \mid x) = 0 \implies (f(y) \mid x) = -(f(x)\mid y).
$$
Now, suppose that $x \in \ker f$. Every element of $\operatorname{im}(f)$ can be expressed as $f(y)$ for some $y \in E$. We note that for any $x \in \ker f$ and $y \in E$, we have
$$
(f(y)\mid x) = -(f(x) \mid y) = -(0 \mid y) = 0.
$$
That is, the elements $x$ and $f(y)$ are orthogonal. In other words, we have deduced that $\ker f$ and $\operatorname{im} f $ are orthogonal subspaces.

By the rank nullity theorem, we know that $\dim \ker f + \dim \operatorname{im} f = \dim E$. Thus, we may deduce that $\ker f$ and $\operatorname{im} f$ are actually orthogonal *complements*.

---

Here's a solution using the adjoint transformation.

Let $f^*$ denote the adjoint of $f$. Using the fact that $(f(x)|x) = 0$ for all $x \in E$, we deduce that $(f^*(x)|x) = 0$ for all $x \in E$, and it follows that the map $g = \frac 12(f + f^*)$ satisfies
$$
(g(x)\mid x) = 0 \quad \text{for all } x \in E.
$$
Deduce from the fact that $g$ is self-adjoint and the above condition that $g=0$. That is, we have $f + f^* = 0 \implies f^* = -f$ (which is to say that $f$ is "skew-adjoint"). For any transformation $f$, we have
$$
\ker(f) = \operatorname{im}(f^*)^\perp,
$$
where $U^\perp$ denotes the orthogonal complement of a subspace $U \subseteq E$.
However, because $f^* = -f$, we deduce that $\operatorname{im}(f^*) = \operatorname{im}(f)$ so that
$$
\ker(f) = \operatorname{im}(f)^\perp.
$$